# Three.js texture on material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to apply a custom image texture (.bmp or .jpg) on a material loaded from Blender and used in my project via the JSONLoader method.

There is no bug but the render of the material with the texture is bad looking.
You can see it here: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/18/1399215240-stack.png

I'd like to get rid of these "rays" on my material. Here is the code I use to load my material/texture:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/Game/models/textures/black.jpg');
var currentMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
var currentModel = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, currentMaterial);
```

The "geometry" variable is the result of the callback of the JSONLoader.Load method.

I'd like to know if the problem comes from the image texture or from the code. And what is the best way to load a material created in Blender and exported as a JS file and loaded with the JSONLoader. I'm not sure if I use the best method when I use the "THREE.MeshBasicMaterial" constructor.

Thanks

Comment: Try `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;` `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` does not support lights; try addiing a light to the scene and use `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` for example.

Comment: Thanks but none of these solutions work. When I try to apply the RepeatWrapping nothing changes, and if I use THREE.MeshLambertMaterial my model becomes black, like if no texture is applied. Adding a light doesn't change anything